# Sorting the datatable works only at first time. but then it doesnt work

Tags: spring, primefaces, datatable

there is my page:

```
<p:dataTable id="selectedLimitServicesTbl"
                widgetVar="selectedLimitServicesTblVar" var="service"
                value="#{massOrderFlowBean.limitServicesBean.limits}"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400"
                selection="#{massOrderFlowBean.limitServicesBean.selectedLimitServices}"
                emptyMessage="#{msg['empty.result.message']}"
                rowKey="#{service.uniqueKey}"
                filteredValue="#{massOrderFlowBean.limitServicesBean.filtered}"
                sortBy="#{service.name}" sortFunction="#{massOrderFlowBean.limitServicesBean.sortByServiceName}">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="selectedLimitServicesTbl"
                    update=":massOrderForm:toConfirmLimitServices" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
                    process="selectedLimitServicesTbl"
                    update=":massOrderForm:toConfirmLimitServices" />
                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="selectedLimitServicesTbl"
                    update=":massOrderForm:toConfirmLimitServices" />

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
                    style="width:25px; text-align:center"/>
                <p:column headerText="#{msg['MassActions.select.service']}"
                    filterBy="#{service.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText style="white-space:normal;" value="#{service.name}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

and my bean:

```
private List<Service> selectedLimitServices;
public List<Service> getSelectedLimitServices() {
    return selectedLimitServices;
  }

  public void setSelectedLimitServices(List<Service> selectedLimitServices) {
    this.selectedLimitServices = selectedLimitServices;
  }
public int sortByServiceName(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    return getStringFromObject(obj1).compareTo(getStringFromObject(obj2));
  }
```

first time i enter the page it sorts fine, but when i go another page and then again go back to the table it does not sort it
whats wrong?

Comment: Better to switch to using a lazyDataModel. More powerful, I use it all the time

Comment: @Kukeltje and how to use it?

Comment: start with the pf showcase